# Compartir la instancia de un objeto en diferentes clases de un form c#

Tags: c#

Soy algo inexperto en este tema, tengo un aplicación en **`C#`** con diferentes formularios pero prácticamente mi problema es el siguiente:

tengo 3 forms y para poder pasar variables entre ellos cree una clase:

```
public class Oportunidad
{
    private string Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
}
```

la cual instancia un objeto en mi **form 1** para acceder a sus atributos Cliente, Area y Pais, y asignarles un valor:

```
Oportunidad objeto = new Oportunidad();
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, mi pregunta es...

¿Cómo podría compartir esa misma instancia en el **form 2 y 3** para que ese objeto siempre contenga el mismo valor en sus atributos? ya que sé que cuando creo una instancia de ese objeto en otros **form** se restablece el objeto y ya no guarda e valor que tenia en mi **form1**
Lo que intente fue instanciarlo desde el main:

**main**

```
Oportunidad oportunidad = new Oportunidad();
```

y tratar de solo inicializar el objeto en mi **form 1** para poder acceder a esa instancia que ya está creada:

**Form1**

```
Oportunidad objeto;
objeto.Cliente;
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a saber esto que sé que es muy básico.

Gracias.

Comment: Lee sobre cómo implementar un patrón singleton en tu aplicación

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una aplicación de ese tipo siempre tiene un formulario base donde en este, pueden partir otros formularios. 
Ahí es donde debes instanciar la clase Oportunidad (en el formulario base).
Por ejemplo, imagínate que tenemos:
Un formulario llamado Form1, aquí habrá dos botones que enlazarán a dos posibles formularios (Form2 y Form3).
En Form1 es donde deberías instanciar la clase Oportunidad. Adicionalmente, harás uso de los contructores de la clase Form2 y Form3 para poder recibir la dirección base del objeto(op) tipo Oportunidad y de ese modo, podrás usar el mismo objeto sin instanciar de nuevo.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
     private Oportunidad op = new Oportunidad();
     public Form()
     {
         //InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void buttonForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Form3 a = new Form3(op);
         a.ShowDialog();
     }

     private void buttonForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Form2 a = new Form2(op);
         a.ShowDialog();
     }
}
```

El código de las clases Form2 y Form3 sería:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    private Oportunidad op;
    public Form2(Oportunidad op)
    {
       this.op = op;
    }
}

class Form3 : Form
{
    private Oportunidad op;
    public Form3(Oportunidad op)
    {
       this.op = op;
    }
}
```

Hay otra forma de efectuarlo y es haciendo la variable de instancia como estática en la clase Form1:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
     public static Oportunidad Op { get; set;} 
     public Form()
     {
         //InitializeComponent();
         Op = new Oportunidad();
     }

     private void buttonForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Form3 a = new Form3();
         a.ShowDialog();
     }

     private void buttonForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Form2 a = new Form2();
         a.ShowDialog();
     }
}
```

Y luego en la clase Form1 o Form2 lo usas de esta forma:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
       MessageBox.Show(Form1.Op.Area);
    }
}
```

De este modo nos ahorramos haciendo uso del constructor.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano! tu solución me ayudo igual que la de Leandro Tuttini. Disculpa mi ignorancia, soy algo novato en este tema. Me surge casi la misma duda que le planteaba a Leandro Tuttini, ya que él creo una clase estática y en tu solución fue directa la propiedad. Me casua duda el saber el porqué de una u otra y cuál sería mejor usar.
De antemano mil gracias bro!!! me ayudaste muchísimo.

Comment: @UseIP La diferencia es que en una clase estática, todos los miembros (atributos, propiedades y métodos) deberán ser estáticos, es decir, no podrás instanciar la clase. La forma como te lo planteé, solo asigné como estático la propiedad porqué lo hice adentro de una clase de instancia (una clase que no es estática). Puedes usar cualquiera de las dos formas, pero ten en cuenta que en una clase estática no podrás tener métodos ni atributos de instancia. Y si te sirvió mi respuesta, no olvides de darme un voto.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de explicarte una solución simple (ni mejor, ni peor, ni nada, si no una solución que puedas enteder), corrijamos un detalle en tu pregunta.

> ya que sé que cuando creo una instancia de ese objeto en otros form se
>   restablece el objeto y ya no guarda e valor que tenia en mi form1

No es eso lo que pasa. Cuando creas otra instancia de otro objeto, es exactamente eso, otra instancia de tu objeto. Salvo que el objeto tenga propiedades `STATIC`, cada instancia de un objeto es otro objeto distinto. Pero estan todos vivos al mismo tiempo, no es que perdes el anterio.

Como detalle, los form tambien son objetos como cualquier otro.. y podes abrir tantos como quieras.

Ahora, facilmente lo que podes hacer es lo siguiente. Quien abre los form, crea una instancia del objeto que queres

```
Oportunidad objeto = new Oportunidad();
```

(Nota, usa nombres de variables que sean representativas).

y en cada form que haces, creas una propiedad publica de esta forma:

```
public Oportunidad miclase;
```

Y una vez que haces la creacion del form, antes de abrirlo, le pasas ese valor:

```
Form1 formulario1 = new Form1();
formulario1.miclase = objeto;
Form2 formulario2 = new Form2();
formulario2.miclase = objeto;
```

Y de esta forma,todos estan apuntado a la misma instancia del objeto.

Comment: Hermano, muchísimas gracias por tu retroalimentación, si tenia pensado esa descripción de la instancia del objeto, que realmente se crea otra instancia, mas no se reinicia este mismo.
Estoy tratando de hacerlo de todas las formas que me recomendaron, pero de esta forma que mencionas, la clase no es estática cierto?
De antemano gracias bro! me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: @UseIP recuerda acpetar la respuesta que te ayudo... sea cual sea...

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas simple es poner como `static` una propiedad en una `class`

```
public static class SharedData{
    public static Oportunidad Oportunidad {get;set;}
}
```

de esta forma desde el Form1 usarias

```
public void button1_click(...){
      SharedData.Oportunidad = new Oportunidad(){
          Cliente = txtCliente.Text,
          Area = "",
          Pais = ""
      };

}
```

desde los otros forms recuperas los datos

```
public void form_Load(...){
      var oportunidad = SharedData.Oportunidad;
      txtxCliente.Text = oportunidad.Cliente 
}
```

otra forma seria usando el patron `Singleton`

Comment: Gracias Bro! Estoy haciéndolo de todas las formas que me recomendaron. No sabes como me ayudo tu solución, muchísimas gracias!! solo que una pregunta, realmente no entiendo el porqué de crear una clase estática y asignarle ese atributo de tipo Oportunidad. Por lo que investigue vi que no se puede instanciar una clase static, por ello supuse que primeramente se creaba una clase estatica. Disculpa mi ignorancia, sé que es súper básico, pero soy bastante novato en este tema. Muchas gracias por tu apoyo bro!